# Unique signal problem - No one heard of such problem

Tags: network-signal

I am using honor 4x from past 1 year. From last week I am facing a unique issue. 
SIM 2 signal is not working with Vodafone in some areas of the city (for example it will not work in my home). Vodafone Signal is perfect with other mobiles in my home. Same Vodafone sim is working perfectly when I go to office (just 3 KM away from home). I tried to swap SIM-1 & 2. My BSNL SIM works normal either in SIM-1 or SIM-2 slots. 
Following things I tried.
Put Vodafone SIM in SIM 1 - Same problem.
Tried some other Vodafone SIM - Same problem.
Put the Vodafone SIM in another mobile - Works perfectly.
Calling to that Vodafone number while in home - Message says "Seems you dialed a wrong number".
Changed the Vodafone SIM for same number - No luck, it wont work in home.
Experimented with lot of setting changes - No luck. It works, without any settings changes it works normally in my office.
Called Vodafone call center - No use, they never heard such problem .
Can any one suggest me what could be the problem.

Comment: Appears to me it is a tower linked problem-the one you are connected to while at home. Probably it is maxed out in capacity - you can check if others in neighborhood also face this problem and complain to service provider if they do. If it is only you..I have no idea why it is happening